# Static storage duration for a string

Tags: c, string-literals

In testing the following:

```
char* x = "Hello";
printf("%s %p %p %p", "Hello", x, "Hello", "Hello");
```

> Hello  
> 0x5618b7d478c7 
> 0x5618b7d478c7 
> 0x5618b7d478c7

I noticed that the `"Hello"` has the same memory address in all cases, meaning that the compiler stores the string `"Hello"` one time in `.rodata` (as it should).

Is this part of the language specification in that whenever a string-literal is used it should be looked up to see if it already exists before storing it? Or is this considered a compiler optimization to not store duplicate strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the behavior depends on compiler options. You can set that the compiler will store identical string literals as one string literal or as different string literals.

So you should not relay on a condition like this

```
if ( "Hello" == "Hello" )
```

that it will be evaluated as true.

According to the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 **It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values.** If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is allowed to do such optimizations with strings and compound literals. These may share storage, as long as their values are correctly presented to the application. But on the other hand there is no obligation to do so.

Other objects, variables, all are guaranteed to occupy storage of their own, even if the contents ist the same, such that all these objects have a unique address.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the arrays created for string literals, C 2018 6.4.5 7 says:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

This means the compiler is allowed to use the same or different memory for identical strings, as its designers choose. That includes strings that are substrings of others, such as `"world"` and `"Hello world"`.

Comment: does that mean it's up to the compiler how it deals with repetitions?

Comment: Yes. A compiler is allowed, but not required to do this optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is considered a compiler optimization. It is named [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). On GCC, it is enabled by [`-fmerge-constants`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).